# Getting error: TypeError: object of type 'Phone' has no len()

Tags: python

I am getting "TypeError: object of type 'Phone' has no len()"
and "'Phone' object has no attribute '**getitem**'" 
can anyone elaborate?

```
class Phone(object):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def number(number):
        '''Test if the number is valid or not'''

        for i in range(number):

            n = ''.join(i for i in number if i.isdigit())

            if (len(n) >= 12) or (len(n) <= 9):
                return '0' * 10
            elif len(n) == 11 and n[0] != 1:
                return '0' * 10
            elif n[0] == 1 and len(n) == 11:
                return n.pop[0]
            else:
                return n
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: And the correct indentation.

Comment: What code causes those errors? Please show your entire `Phone` declaration (properly indented)

Comment: For starters, `self.number = number` will overwrite the `number` method.

Comment: You are using `number`for 3 different things, use other names!

Answer (score 1):

Two different exceptions make me think that You  have few versions of code tested and proposed one is not one where You got these errors. Because in this case

```
self.number = number
```

should overwrite the number method

But It seems that problem is following:

First argument for instance method should be `self`. In any case instance is passed as first argument into bound method

So `number` in method `number` is `Phone` instance.

It seems that You are trying to operate with this `number` (which is self) as with string and so You got these exceptions:

> "TypeError: object of type 'Phone' has no len()" and "'Phone' object has no attribute 'getitem'"